# is there any plugin that can transform input type file based on user media to capture photos?

Tags: jquery, mobile, file-upload, image-uploading, getusermedia

well the idea is, i want user to upload photos.

source of photos can be webcam/mobile cam/mobile gallery/ simple desktop file upload.

and i want to have option of multiple photos as well :) -greedy humhum-

i currently use getUserMedia to capture webcam if available. other wise basic old plain `<input type='file' />` and in case its a mobile i add `accept="image/*" capture="camera"` to the input file.

Now my question is there any available mature and stable jquery plugin out there that can do this ?

i mean like detect all devices connected to getUserMedia and show a dialog to select source (webcam/mobile cam/mobile gallery/ simple desktop file upload) ?

This would be very helpful as it will save hours of coding and debugging to do it. and will be a universal smart photo upload plugin :)

thanks